# Why can't I just use "url(imageURL)" to set a background pictuer?

Tags: javascript

```
<img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" 
src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg"
 onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">

function upDate(previewPic) 
{
 imageURL = previewPic.src;
 document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage =  "url('" + imageURL + "')";
}
```

Why should I use `"url('" + imageURL + "')"` to set background image?
I had tried to use `"url(imageURL)"` but it couldn't work.

Comment: If you use `"url(imageURL)"`  then the url is literally `imageURL`, but you want to have the actual value of the variable `imageURL`,  so you need to to use either  `"url('" + imageURL + "')"`  or `"url(" + imageURL + ")";`. In modern js you can also use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: @t.niese I was going to say the same about template literals. +1

Comment: @t.niese   Could you tell me the reason to use  +

Comment: Why do you expect that, `var url="test";   document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "url(image.jpg)"` would result in `document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "test(image.jpg)";`? (I intentionally used `url` instead of `imageURL`, maybe that helps to understand it)  Everything between quotes is just a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageURL` is a `variable`, the `url` function needs a string  so it makes sense to put it between quotes so that it evaluates its content ( path to the picture)

Answer (score 0):

You are using ImageURL as a variable so inside quote tag that becomes a string so you need to put direct image file inside